# How to interact with a process with its PID

Tags: linux, bash, process

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 . I would like to know how can I do operations on a process through its PID . I don't know whether is it possible or not. If possible help me on this. Operations means status, properties of the process and sending commands and data to process through it PID .

EDIT: Status means its working statistics, for example how much RAM it's consuming. Properties means information regrading that process. The main thing I want to know here is about sending commands/data to process through its PID.

Comment: What _status_? What _properties_? What _commands_? (Unix-like systems support _signals_, see `signals(7)` for one easy example of what you can send to a process.)

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve this information casually from a command line?  Are you trying to do it from a program? If so, what programming language are you using? What do you mean, "sending commands and data to the process through its PID?" Please give an example, to help narrow down the question.

Comment: by using either C or Python i want to contact my process and i would like to do operations on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) is something you should have a look at. It provides a lot of information on the process. Here is the [manpage for proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc).
Basically, you cd to `/proc/$PID` and all those pseudo files contain info you should be able to look at.

Otherwise, a good program to play with is `top`, or even better, [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/). It can send all sorts of signals, and you can observe a lot of info (status, mem usage, cpu usage,...) It's really great.

Apart from that it's not clear what you're looking to do, so I'm staying pretty generic. If you want to do IPC (inter process communication) as sarnold said, signals might be the way to go, or mmap. (memory-mapped file)

Comment: ok how to send some signals to process . i mean sending some variables or commands to the process through it PID .

Answer (score 1):

ps, kill and top are commonly used to interact with processes, please read their man pages.

ps gives snapshot,usually to grab pid from the proc name though:

e.g. `ps aux | grep -i sshd`

top gives semi-continuous feedback (like a configurable windows task manager...sorta)

In my opinion top will give a good idea of mem usage. You'll need to use top's interactive commands to configure for best output though. Press 'o' for sorting and 'f' for fields I think, read the man.

kill sends SIGTERM by default (or something w/e it stops the process) or use kill -9 if proc  handler is ignoring SIGTERMs, kill -s SIGNAL can be used to send ANY signal though like SIGSTOP (stops proc) and SIGCONT (continues proc)

Answer (score 1):

Different programs have different way of taking process id as parameter. Man page is you help here.

Now for example `top` will give most of the basic system stats. To get the top result for a process say `X`, this command will give you the required result `top -n1 -b -p <pid of X>`

Also `/proc/<pid>` dir will have all the necessary system stats, all you need is know where and how to read those data.